# Qthread with reading json values and sending json with toggle button issues

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyside2, qthread

I have some issues when toggle button is set to OFF it goes back to ON as json read still gets not refreshed value and kicks in slot_method. But I need this if statement to read initial value when launching the app and this mode allready can be selected from hardware controller. How it can be reworked that on toggle button click 1 json read thread could be excluded ?

**py_toggle.py**

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class PyToggle(QCheckBox):
    def __init__(
            self,
            width=60,
            bg_color="#777",
            circle_color="#DDD",
            active_color="#3A3A66",
            animation_curve=QEasingCurve.OutBounce
    ):
        QCheckBox.__init__(self)

        # SET DEFAULT PARAMETERS
        self.setFixedSize(width, 28)
        self.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)

        # COLORS

        self._bg_color = bg_color
        self._circle_color = circle_color
        self._active_color = active_color

        # CREATE ANIMATION

        self._circle_position = 3
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"circle_position", self)
        self.animation.setEasingCurve(animation_curve)
        self.animation.setDuration(400)  # Time in milliseconds

        # CONNECT STATE CHANGED

        # self.stateChanged.connect(self.debug)
        self.stateChanged.connect(self.start_transition)
        # self.stateChanged.connect()

    # CREATE NEW SET AND GET PROPERTIE

    @Property(float)  # Decorator Getter
    def circle_position(self):
        return self._circle_position

    @circle_position.setter
    def circle_position(self, pos):
        self._circle_position = pos
        self.update()

    # def state(self):
    #     print(f"Status: {self.isChecked()}")

    def start_transition(self, value):
        self.animation.stop()  # Stop animation if running
        if value:
            self.animation.setEndValue(self.width() - 26)
        else:
            self.animation.setEndValue(3)
        # START ANIMATION
        self.animation.start()

    # SET NEW HIT AREA

    def hitButton(self, pos: QPoint):
        return self.contentsRect().contains(pos)

    # DRAW NEW ITEMS
    def paintEvent(self, e):
        p = QPainter(self)
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        # SET AS NO PEN
        p.setPen(Qt.NoPen)

        # DRAW RECTANGLE
        rect = QRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())

        if not self.isChecked():
            # DRAW BG
            p.setBrush(QColor(self._bg_color))
            p.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, rect.width(), self.height(), self.height() / 2, self.height() / 2)

            # DRAW CIRCLE
            p.setBrush(QColor(self._circle_color))
            p.drawEllipse(self._circle_position, 3, 22, 22)
        else:
            # DRAW BG
            p.setBrush(QColor(self._active_color))
            p.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, rect.width(), self.height(), self.height() / 2, self.height() / 2)

            # DRAW CIRCLE
            p.setBrush(QColor(self._circle_color))
            p.drawEllipse(self._circle_position, 3, 22, 22)

        # END DRAW
        p.end()
```

**test.py**

```
import sys

import requests
from PySide2.QtCore import (QTimer, QThread, Signal)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

from py_toggle import PyToggle


class WorkerThread(QThread):
    measurements_signals = Signal(str, name = 'm_signals')  # declare the signal

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda: WorkerThread.run(self))
        self.timer.setInterval(6000)  # 6000ms = 6s
        self.timer.start()

    def run(self):
        url = "http://192.168.8.150/json"

        try:
            res = requests.get(url)
            msg = res.json()
            print(msg)
            try:
                if res.status_code == 200:
                    quiet = msg["heatpump"][18]["Value"]
                    self.measurements_signals.emit(quiet)
                else:
                    print("Not Working")
            except requests.exceptions.InvalidURL or requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as err:
                print(err)

        except requests.exceptions.InvalidURL or requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as err:
            print(err)

    def stop(self):
        self.terminate()
        print("stop")


class Tester(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Tester, self).__init__(parent)


        # ==> TOGGLE BUTTON1
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.resize(200, 150)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.toggle = PyToggle()
        layout.addWidget(self.toggle)
        self.toggle.stateChanged.connect(self.postCommand)
        self.setLayout(layout)



        # ==> Worker Thread start

        self.wt = WorkerThread()  # This is the thread object
        self.wt.start()
        # Connect the signal from the thread to the slot_method
        self.wt.measurements_signals.connect(self.slot_method)  ### 3) connect to the slot
        app.aboutToQuit.connect(self.wt.stop)  # to stop the thread when closing the GUI

    def slot_method(self, quiet):

        if quiet == "1":
            self.toggle.setChecked(True)

    def postCommand(self):
        if self.toggle.isChecked():
            setting = "SetQuietMode=1"
        else:
            setting = "SetQuietMode=0"

        url = f"http://192.168.8.150/command?{setting}"
        r = requests.request('GET', url)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Tester()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure I'm understanding the question. Do you want to toggle the checkbox based on some default value avoiding calling `postCommand()` when starting the application? Then do it before connecting, alternatively temporarily disconnect the signal from the function or use QSignalBlocker.

Comment: @musicamante when application is launched it reads json ant updates toggle to True or False, every 6s read are performed.  When I push toggle to False position my self, postCommand sends json value 0 but read from run in WorkerThread still gets 1 (old value) and my toggle goes to True position because of slot_method which is used to update initial value.  I need somehow to delay when postCommand is issued.

Comment: Uhm. There are a couple of problems in your code. First of all, the WorkerThread is actually run just *once* as a separate thread, after that, it's just run in the main thread (where QTimer is created and started), making almost useless. Then, `postCommand` is also run in the main thread, which makes me think that you either don't actually need threading (being it local, it probably returns immediately), or you're still using a blocking request when calling the request. So, the real question here is: does the controller actually require some time to reply, or is its response immediate?

Comment: @musicamante it takes some time for controlelr to change value and get new one from actual device. So its not instant change. I believe that postCommand not blocking as I see json responses in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your implementation.

The first one is that the QThread actually runs the function in the separate thread just the first time (when `start()` is called), while the `QTimer` will always execute it in the main thread, where it was created. `run()` should *never* be explicitly called.

Then, and this is the main point of your issue, the signal should always be emitted only when the value changes, not *every time* it is requested.

Finally, since requests are potentially blocking, the command sent from the UI should also be threaded. We already have a thread running, so we could use that along with a python [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html).

There are also other issues:

- as the [documentation explicitly says](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#terminate), `terminate()` is discouraged, as using it could cause problems and stability issues; using a simple flag is way more simple and safer; in any case, with your original code it wouldn't do *nothing* anyway, unless called as soon as the thread is started: as stated above, each further execution was done in the wrong thread, so `terminate()` will do nothing useful;
- the second `try`/`except` block is pointless, as there is no possibility for that type of exception in there; the only exception that would make sense at that point is the `KeyError` for the dictionary lookup;
- the `stateChanged` signal is for *tri-state* checkboxes, for standard dual state the proper signal is `toggled`;

A proper implementation must keep the thread running in a `while` loop, and eventually quit when necessary. Using the queue `timeout` argument we also get the 6 second interval, so there is no need for timers.

```
from queue import Queue, Empty


class WorkerThread(QThread):
    measurements_signals = Signal(str, name = 'm_signals')

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)

        self.queue = Queue()

    def run(self):
        self.keepRunning = True
        url = "http://192.168.8.150/"
        quiet = None

        while self.keepRunning:
            try:
                res = requests.get(url + 'json')
                msg = res.json()
                print(msg)
                if res.status_code == 200:
                    new = msg["heatpump"][18]["Value"]
                    if new != quiet:
                        quiet = new
                        self.measurements_signals.emit(quiet)
                else:
                    print("Not Working")

            except requests.exceptions.InvalidURL or requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as err:
                print(err)

            try:
                q = self.queue.get(timeout=6)
                if q == -1:
                    break
                cmd, value = q
                if cmd == 'SetQuietMode':
                    quiet = value
                requests.request('GET', f'{url}command?{cmd}={value}')

            except Empty:
                pass

    def stop(self):
        print("stop")
        self.keepRunning = False
        self.queue.put(-1)
        self.wait()

    def setQuiet(self, state):
        self.queue.put(('SetQuietMode', int(state)))


class Tester(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # ...
        self.wt = WorkerThread()
        self.wt.measurements_signals.connect(self.slot_method)
        app.aboutToQuit.connect(self.wt.stop)
        self.toggle.toggled.connect(self.wt.setQuiet)

        # it's usually better to start the thread *after* connecting signals
        self.wt.start()

    def slot_method(self, quiet):
        if quiet == "1":
            # temporarily disconnect to avoid calling setQuiet unnecessarily
            self.toggle.toggled.disconnect(self.wt.setQuiet)
            self.toggle.setChecked(True)
            self.toggle.toggled.connect(self.wt.setQuiet)
```

Note that QtNetwork module provides the [QNetworkAccessManager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html), which already works asynchronously. Using that, you can avoid creating a separate thread class and you will be able to extend the program's functionality much more easily.

Comment: I get same issues with your code as well, when I set toggle to False it goes back to True state instantly, doing second time stays in False position as expected. Increased timeout value doesn't help here.

Comment: @Vaikis2006 comment `if cmd == 'SetQuietMode': quiet = value`. The timeout is *after* the status query and *before* the command, so the query request is done immediately right after that. In any case, I cannot obviously test the code, since I don't have the device, so you must do some efforts in understanding the logic of the code above and eventually fix it to your needs.

Comment: seems this suggestion helped to avoid previous issues, thanks !

Comment: could you explain this part in your code :  `q = self.queue.get(timeout=6)
                if q == -1:
                    break
                cmd, value = q`